# Как скачать сайт?

Tags: html, css, вёрстка

Как скачать сайт с помощью f12 без какого-либо вспомогательного софта/сайта?

учусь верстке и хотелось бы просто посмотреть главные файлы сайта как они написаны index.html и style.css

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: Если «просто посмотреть», то зачем скачивать? Просто открываете в браузере исходный код страницы да и всё

Comment: это не удобно, хотелось бы на vscode его смотреть

Comment: Ну тогда в любом браузере есть пункт меню «Сохранить как»

Comment: спасибо все получилось :)

Answer (score 2):

В гугл хроме или яндекс браузере нажимаете `ctrl + s` или правой кнопкой мыши "и сохранить страницу как", выбираете путь и вам скачается html файл и папка с js b css, а вообще не понимаю зачем скачивать, если вам нужно просто посмотреть.